# Eclipse: no Runtime shown on SAP Cloud Platform server creation

Tags: eclipse, server, sap-business-technology-platform

i'm working on an application that uses a Sap Cloud Platform Server type. The problem is that every now and then the server just loses the "Runtime Environment" and, because of that, it doesn't let me debug/start/stop nor publish anything.
I've seen that SAP just updated the Cockpit between 22nd and 23rd of May, the past week everything was working fine.
When i try to create a new server, after i choose the SAP Cloud Platform server type, i put the region host and go to the next page of the "new server" window, and this message will appear on top of the server creation window:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZtXL.png)

It's not the first time this happen, I've tried to uninstall and install eclipse from scratch but i can't no longer use this option because it's a big mess trying to install and configure all as it was before.
Someone else got this kind of problem? I've already opened a ticket to the SAP support but it's just some kind of non-helpful workaround that do nothing.

Eclipse version is:

- Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers
- Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
- Build id: 20210312-0638

If you guys need some others info, just ask away!

Comment: I do experience the same error. Any solutions so far?